# Help in understanding a clever proof of Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Theorem: $f, g$ are analytic in a region $\Omega . C$ is a circle/rectangle/(simple closed curve) which along with its interior is contained in $\Omega$. Suppose that $|f|>|g|$ on $C$. Then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros inside $C$.

Proof: We want to move from $f$ towards $f+g$. For $0 \leq t \leq 1$, define $f_{t}=f+t g$. Thus at time zero we have $f$ and at time one $f+g$. Observe $f_{t}$ has no zero on $C$. Indeed, if it has then at such a point $z \in C, f(z)=-t g(z)$ so that $|f(z)|=t|g(z)| \leq|g(z)|$ contradicting our assumption. If $n_{t}$ is the number of zeros of $f_{t}$ within $C$, then Theorem 23 tells us
$$
n_{t}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f_{t}^{\prime}(z)}{f_{t}(z)} d z
$$
Since both $f_{t}(z)$ and $f_{t}^{\prime}(z)$ are continuous functions of $(t, z)$, the above integral is a continuous function of $t$. But it is integer valued and hence must be constant. Thus $n_{0}=n_{1}$.

I understand all the steps except why $n_t$ is continuous. Can someone give me a rigorous argument for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
n_{t}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} F(t, z) \, d z
$$
where the integrand
$$
 F(t, z) = \frac{f'(z) + tg'(z)}{f(z) + tg(z)}
$$
is continuous on the *compact* set $[0, 1] \times C$. It follows that $F$ is *uniformly continuous,* and that implies that the integral is a continuous function of the parameter $t$.